# How do we create an Object as source of light in React Three Fiber?

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

Using directional/ point light will generate light from outside but not from inside the Object.

Example: Sun should be the source of light to the Objects around.
Please find the images below to understand the problem statement

[Directional Light Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwy9L.png)
[Point Light Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCD83.png)

I'm trying to make the Sun object as the source of light in React-Three-Fiber

Answer (score 2):

If you make the sun mesh not interact with shadows, the `PointLight` will illuminate right through it, even when placed in the center.

```js
sun.castShadow = false;
sun.receiveShadow = false;
```